# Watir wait_until_present times out instead of returning false

Tags: ruby, testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm still new to testing with Watir, but I've been reading all over the place about [waiting with Watir](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) and I can't find a solution to my problem.

Basically I want `wait_while_present` and `wait_until_present` to work for when the page is loading. When I realized that both were timing out, I tried to write my own janky version using `element.present?` but that times out too. I think it might be an issue with the current version of watir-webdriver.

Here is an example of a test that's giving me a lot of trouble:

```
def test_rows_per_page()
  begin
    browser.element(:id => 'moar-rows').when_present.click
    browser.element(:id => 'loading').wait_while_present
    assert_text = browser.element(:id => 'num-rows').text

    browser.element(:id => 'less-rows').when_present.click
    browser.element(:id => 'loading').wait_while_present
    diff_text = browser.element(:id => 'num-rows').text

    if !(assert_text.eql? diff_text)
      screen_capture()
      assert_passed()
    else
      screen_capture()
      assert_failed()
    end
  rescue
    screen_capture()
    increment_failed() #this is how I know it's timing out
  end
end
```

I tried testing `puts load_element.present?(timeout=1)` and it just fails faster. So `wait_until_present` isn't returning false when the element isn't present. **How do I get it to return false?**

I might try this, which was in response to the question I linked to at the beginning, but I'm not sure if it solves my problem:

```
Timeout::timeout(input_timeout=1) do
  #Default webdriver command here
end
rescue Timeout::Error
  raise TimeoutError
end
```

SO won't let me post more than two links with my pathetically low reputation but the source code for watir-webdriver is on GitHub.

---

I forgot to put the specific context that showed me where it times out:

```
def test_rows_per_page()
  begin
    browser.element(:id => 'moar-rows').when_present.click
    loading_element = element(:id => 'loading')
    #loading_element.wait_while_present
    assert_text = browser.element(:id => 'num-rows').text

    browser.element(:id => 'less-rows').when_present.click
    #loading_element.wait_while_present
    puts loading_element.present? #=> true
    sleep 1
    puts loading_element.present? #times out here
    sleep 1
    puts loading_element.present? 

    diff_text = browser.element(:id => 'num-rows').text
    if !(assert_text.eql? diff_text)
      screen_capture()
      assert_passed()
    else
      screen_capture()
      assert_failed()
    end
  rescue
    screen_capture()
    increment_failed() #this is how I know it's timing out
  end
end
```

---

Commented out `rescue` block, here's the error:

```
:in `eval': unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (550, 565). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loading-screen" class="loading-page-backdrop ng-scope" ng-if="pageLoading || gridLoading"></div>
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
(Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.76)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232908,platform=Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:618:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:375:in `clickElement'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:132:in `click'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:122:in `method_missing'
from /file.rb:208:in `rowsPerPage_next'
```

I'm going to try `browser.div(:id => 'loading-screen').wait_while_present` to see if that works. It was hard to pull either the `id` or the `class` from the loading page HTML since it's only there while it's loading. (I asked the developer for identifiers but I don't like bugging her too much.)

---

More notes:

**My main issue is that `wait_while_present` doesn't seem to continue if the element isn't present.** That's why I tried writing my own janky version using `present?`, but that also times out instead of returning `false` when the element isn't there. I'd much rather have the Watir version just work how it's supposed to.

I've tried both ways with both the `id` and the `class` for the loading div and it's still timing out instead of continuing when the div isn't present.

I currently have these global wait settings if that's at all relevant:

```
browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
browser.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 30
Watir.default_timeout = 30
```

`present?` is supposed to return `true` if the element both exists and is visible, so if the loading div isn't visible then it should just return `false`, right? Even if it it exists but is hidden? I really tried figuring this out on my own.

Please just tell me I'm crazy and there's some easy way to fix this, like reinstalling Ruby or something.

Comment: What is the timeout error that you get? It would also help if the script showed where you were calling `.present?`.

Comment: When it times out it goes to `rescue`, so I just get the output from `increment_failed()`. I commented out the `wait_while_present` lines and threw in a `puts load_element.present?(timeout=1)` and it fails after whatever length of time I set for the timeout.

Comment: I added another code block for more context.

Comment: I think you need to be careful when debugging with a `rescue` clause. For example, `load_element.present?(timeout=1)` is going to the rescue clause because of an ArgumentError, `present?` does not take any arguments, not because of a timeout. Removing the `rescue` (or at least capturing and outputting the exception) would allow you to see the actual stack trace and get a better understanding of what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the timeout thing after I tried it one more time. I commented out the `rescue` block and it threw an error, give me a minute to sanitize and post it.

Comment: So I ran it in debug mode, and if I call `browser.div(:id => 'loading-screen').wait_while_present` after the loading screen disappears then it waits the amount I set for my global wait time. How do I get it to just continue to the next line if the element isn't present to begin with? (This was my original issue, actually.)

Comment: `wait_while_present` already continues if the element is not present to begin with. Based on the exception, it just looks like you are waiting on the wrong element. The script is waiting on the id "loading", but the error says the element in the way has id "loading-screen".

Comment: Originally I just wrote a generic version of the script in my post because it's all internal company stuff and I want to avoid being too specific, but I tested it on the actual ids and classes from the loading page on the site and it hasn't been continuing like I'd expect. This has been driving me nuts for weeks. (Btw I really appreciate your help with this. Wish I could buy you a beer.)

Comment: It is hard to answer this without being able to see the page. But, based on the information so far, I can only imagine a couple of issues. (1) There are multiple loading elements with the same id and the one that is displayed is not the first one in the HTML. (2) There is a timing issue - the loading element starts hidden, Watir checks/waits for it to be hidden, then the loading element appears.

Comment: There error you included above has nothing to do with a wait method, it's a click method that fails when it cannot locate the element.  whatever was on line 208 if your code at the time you captured that error.  Therefore  your presumption that .present? is malfunctioning is false.

Comment: You're right, I just fixed the click issue today. The browser wasn't scrolling to the bottom successfully because it would (ineffectively) try to scroll to the bottom before the loading spinner went away, so then the next page button wouldn't be visible for Watir to click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to give in and leave the `sleep`s.

(Ignore the random changes in the `class` and `id` names throughout my post. Also `snake_case` vs. `camelCase`. I didn't write it this way. Trust that I'm successfully getting to the HTML elements in question.)

```
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (550, 565). 
Other element would receive the click: <div id="dashboard-loading-screen" class="loading-page-backdrop ng-scope" 
ng-if="pageLoading || gridLoading"></div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError) (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.76)
```

Here's a sanitized version of the entire test that's driving me crazy. I don't have the loading issue in debug mode because of course when I'm debugging it has plenty of time to load, so I had to throw in a bunch of `put`s to figure out what line it was failing on.

Also note that I didn't write the original version of this test, I'm just trying to get it to assert correctly.

```
def dashboard_rowsPerPage_next(targetRows)
  begin
    dashboard_rowsPerPage_internal(targetRows) #click drop-down to choose num of rows/page
    browser.scroll.to :bottom
    beforeRowsText = $browser.div(:class => 'grid-rows-of-label').when_present.text.split(" ", 4).last #page 1

    #I put this instead of wait_while_present
    if (puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope"))
      Watir::Wait.while { browser.html.include? "loading-page-backdrop ng-scope"}
    end
    puts 'a'
    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")
    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")

    #here's where I get the error message
    browser.span(:class, "k-icon k-i-arrow-e").when_present.click 
    puts 'b'
    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")

    if (puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope"))
      Watir::Wait.while { browser.html.include? "loading-page-backdrop ng-scope"}
    end

    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")
    puts 'c'
    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")
    browser.scroll.to :bottom
    puts browser.html.include?("loading-page-backdrop ng-scope")
    afterRowsText = browser.div(:class => 'grid-rows-of-label').when_present.text.split(" ", 4).last #page 2
    puts 'd'
    Watir::Wait.while { browser.html.include? "dashboard-loading-screen"}

    if (!(beforeRowsText.eql? afterRowsText)) #page 2 text should not be the same as page 1 text
      screenCapture()
      assertPassed()
    else
      screenCapture()
      assertFailed()
    end
#  rescue
#    screenCapture()
#    increment_failed()
  end
end
```

So my output is: (comments added for clarity)

```
true #should wait while loading image is visible before puts 'a'
a
true #this means the loading page is still visible, while isn't working
true
unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (550, 565). 
Other element would receive the click: <div id="dashboard-loading-screen" class="loading-page-backdrop ng-scope" 
ng-if="pageLoading || gridLoading"></div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError) (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.76)
```

I checked the values of beforeRowsText and afterRowsText and it's getting those values correctly.

So I'm going to do this instead, because I'm weak:

```
def dashboard_rowsPerPage_next(targetRows)
  begin
    dashboard_rowsPerPage_internal(targetRows) #click drop-down to choose num of rows/page
    browser.scroll.to :bottom
    beforeRowsText = $browser.div(:class => 'grid-rows-of-label').when_present.text.split(" ", 4).last #page 1
    sleep 10
    browser.span(:class, "k-icon k-i-arrow-e").when_present.click 
    sleep 10
    browser.scroll.to :bottom
    afterRowsText = browser.div(:class => 'grid-rows-of-label').when_present.text.split(" ", 4).last #page 2

    if (!(beforeRowsText.eql? afterRowsText)) #page 2 text should not be the same as page 1 text
      screenCapture()
      assertPassed()
    else
      screenCapture()
      assertFailed()
    end
  rescue
    screenCapture()
    increment_failed()
  end
end
```

Wait no, nevermind. It works with 25 rows per page but I get the same error on 50 rows per page.

Comment: The way you are using it. `include?` just tells you if that thing is anywhere in the HTML, it does NOT tell you if the thing is visible or hidden by client side code and/or CSS rules etc.   that method is a poor choice for debugging

Answer (score 2):

It would appear you completely misunderstand the purpose of the wait functions.  I say this because you said

> My main issue is that wait_while_present doesn't seem to continue if
>   the element isn't present.

**THAT BEHAVIOR IS BY DESIGN**

While the `.present?' method returns true or false (which is what you would expect for ANY method written in ruby that ends with a question mark) that is not how the various 'wait' functions work.  Nor, would it be reasonable to assume they did return true or false, since their method names do not end in question marks.

The purpose of those wait functions is to wait up until a specified duration for an expected condition that ***should* or *must* manifest** (as opposed to might) and then proceed, or to raise an error if the timeout expired without the condition being fulfilled.  You can:

- Wait for an element to be present
- Wait for an element to become present
- Wait for a condition to become true
- Wait until a condition becomes false

The presumption when synchronizing using these methods is that: if the timeout has been exceeded the script cannot reliably continue.  Thus the test fails at that point.

This business of raising errors (aka exceptions) to fail a test is pretty much standard behavior for all common testing frameworks in nearly all languages.. cucumber, rspec, junit, minitest, nunit, etc   Test assertions/expectations work the same way, if the thing being asserted fails, an error is raised.  The framework 'catches' the error, records the details as part of the test results, fails that test/scenario and moves on to the next one.  If any method being executed during the test fails, such as trying to click a button that does not exist, an error is raised and the test fails.

For what you want to do, to make use of these methods you would need to wrap the wait call in exception handling code to 'rescue' the error if the method ends up raising an error  Or write your own method for doing waits in a situation where you want to wait for some period of time for a condition that *might* manifest, and then respond conditionally according to the outcome, instead of just raising an error.

Dealing with a web page that has a lot of dynamic client side rendering in response to user actions can be really tricky when there is no easy way to know if the client side code is busy updating the page, waiting for a response to a service call, or waiting for user input.  There is no convention for that, and no standard way to tell which is the case.  If you are lucky, or your programmer cares about test-ability, then they might help you out with something you can use to determine which is the case.  For example many sites have a spinner icon that they display whenever client side code is busy updating the page or getting data from servers, and you can then use visibility of that element to know when your code needs to wait or when it is safe to proceed.

Keep in mind that those methods can take parameters to set the timeout, AND in some cases the error message.. making use of that can greatly enhance your ability to troubleshoot..

for example if you had a really reliable spinner, you could do something like this to wait up to three seconds for it to appear, then up to 10 seconds for it to go away

```
b.element(:id => 'loading').wait_until_present(timeout=3)
b.element(:id => 'loading').wait_while_present(timeout=10)
```

If we want that to not fail if the spinner never appears, and just keep going, but fail if it was there longer than 10 seconds, then you could do some basic [exception handling](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) like this

```
begin
  b.element(:id => 'loading').wait_until_present(timeout=3)
rescue
  puts "waited three seconds without seeing spinner"
end
b.element(:id => 'loading').wait_while_present(timeout=10)
```

Without access to the page you are testing, it is difficult for anyone else to make specific suggestions about how you can get your code synced with the page in a robust way that is still performant.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. This is my first internship and I've been using Watir for about a month so I've been doing a lot of trial-and-error. We have a spinner icon (that's what `element(:id => "loading")` was meant to represent) and I was using `wait_while_present` on that element, but I guess the spinner doesn't show up consistently enough for me use it that way.

Comment: yeah that can be tough.  what you could try is make a 'wait for spinner' helper method, it could include some tiny waits like .1 or .2 to allow time for it to appear, then wait while present, then maybe another tiny wait, and another wait while present..   basically to be sure it's not around.  a bit of a kludge.   interact manually with the site and pay really close attention to delays between when you click, when/if you see a spinner, how long of a delay between the click and the spinner.  if it is very consistent, wait until present followed by wait while present might work.

Comment: I would encourage you to see if you can talk to the programmer who owns that page, and ask them what is happening under the covers when those things are clicked to expand stuff, and also ask how you might be able to know when it is safe to proceed.  maybe they will have some ideas.   Also I am guessing maybe you are learning Ruby at the same time you are learning watir?

Comment: I wrote my own `if element.present? {Watir::wait.until { !(element.present?) } }` etc. method but that didn't do much to help. Yeah, I'm learning Ruby and I'm only about eight months into my CS degree. I think management is getting annoyed at me taking so much time on this, but I feel like it's important to handle the loading spinner throughout the test automation. I have access to the front-end code (but I don't really know JavaScript) so I'll talk to the developer about how that works.

Comment: if you are going to use a spinner, it's gotta be really reliable where and when they use it..

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning ruby/watir/cucumber, and i also wanted a wait that would just give me False if timed out.
 i wanted to wait for about 10 seconds for a pop up to appear or not, and then continue the code. Using sleep 10 is a big waste in case the pop up appears in less than a second, for example. As a beginner, the best way i found to do this is using If blocks. i check if the element is present, and if is not, i wait 3 more seconds. for a maximum of 9 seconds. It solved my problem.

Example: i want to check if a pop up with word "Success" appears. If yes, it prints "Passed". If it does not appear in 9 seconds, it prints "Failed".

```
if $browser.element(:text => "Success").exists? == False
sleep 3
end

if $browser.element(:text => "Success").exists? == False
sleep 3
end

if $browser.element(:text => "Success").exists? == False
sleep 3
end

if $browser.element(:text => "Success").exists? == False
puts "Failed"
end

if $browser.element(:text => "Success").exists?
puts "Passed"
end

test continues
```

Maybe this helps somehow!